# Can varargs be captured by a const type parameter?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript 5.0 introduces [const type parameters](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#const-type-parameters). Is it possible to capture varargs by such a type parameter?

The following function tries doing so:

```
function insertIf<const V extends any[]>(condition: boolean, ...value: V): V | readonly [] {
    if (condition) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the return type is always derived to being `any[] | readonly []`, irrespective of the actual arguments that are given to the function.

An example call is `insertIf(true, { s: 'a' }, { s: '?'})`

Comment: Please [edit] provide a [mre] that shows "the actual arguments that are given to the function", so we have something common to test against.  Presumably you just need to make it `const V extends readonly any[]` instead, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQRpYN), but I don't want to guess about what args you're passing. Once you edit, let me know if my suggested code works for you. If it does I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm also unclear.  I put it into TS playground and the `return value` shows the exact type you've assigned to it.  Seems to work as far as I can tell.  What specifically do you expect it to do with different inputs?

Comment: Changing the type parameter definition from `const V extends any[]` into `const V extends readonly any[]` as suggested, fixes the issue. Many thanks, @jcalz ! It would be interesting what subtle mechanism is involved here, though.

Answer (score 2):

You should change the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `V` from `any[]` to a [`readonly` array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) like `readonly any[]`:

```
function insertIf<const V extends readonly any[]>(
    condition: boolean, ...value: V
): V | readonly [] {
    if (condition) { return value; } else { return []; }
}

const x = insertIf(true, { s: 'a' }, { s: '?' });
// const x: readonly [] | readonly [{ readonly s: "a"; }, { readonly s: "?"; }]
```

---

In the description of [microsoft/TypeScript#51865](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51865), the pull request that implemented [`const` type parameters](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#const-type-parameters) it says:

> When a `const` type parameter is constrained to an array type, that array type should include a `readonly` modifier; otherwise, inferences for the type parameter will fail to meet the constraint.

So with your original version:

```
function insertIf<const V extends any[]>(
    condition: boolean, ...value: V
): V | readonly [] {
    if (condition) { return value; } else { return []; }
}

const x = insertIf(true, { s: 'a' }, { s: '?' });
// const x: any[] | readonly []
```

The compiler actually does want to infer `V` to be `readonly [{ readonly s: "a"; }, { readonly s: "?"; }]` here, as if you'd used a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).  But that type is *not* assignable to `any[]`; readonly arrays have fewer known methods compared to normal read-write arrays.

So then that inference step fails, and the compiler falls back to the constraint of `any[]`, which passes the type check and you get what looks like a silent failure of your code.

---

This is definitely a point of confusion and has been reported as a bug before, see [microsoft/TypeScript#51931](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51931), and it might be nice if the compiler warned you in some way that the `const` modifier wasn't going to work well, but at least for now this is working as intended and the solution is to add that `readonly` modifier.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAhATgewNYWEg3gFBIlIBmArsPAC4CWGedwUEaNAkmQDzyNQ0kANSQQAHjVwATKEhDAAngG0AugD4AFMVI6+wKXXqMAXEgBGGDABsI8gDRIAdM4BuIKxQimh2kgEpvJAAfJDRbKUYrBSRVAl8dJDoyJA09AyNgPwJQiBoKNDw3DwgAbiQAX1ErVmywvIKYlTLy+JbdfkExJABeRJY2TjINGjRPB3wkKFMAchBpivHJmYB+efK-EviAei3yKloGJn72Lm55ZXVUxnTD0wtrW2AHZ0ciz1Nz1QC5RViQsJAEWAUUa2wAVEg9AIkGIPr8VMEcoDItFYmCtoQWoRCKBILAEMgAGJ0MQQKRxHSUagZPqsE48KGCETiST6WQAoEgz6XeLtfSGW7mSw2exOVzud7CeLfET-cIoxoUhIkJIpNICxhZCZ1fKFCWlCpVGra3K6xrNVrxRkwnq0gZcYajCCLKZIWZrF0rNYbcGQjow0wchV-JGc1Em5HA6KugBEIBjzUWQajSyQMeWCYqCPRmKAA)