# Return variadic tuple for nested prop

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function `fc` which takes 2 objects and returns a merged version of them, in a fully type-safe manner:

```
const rfc = fc({ num: [1, 2, 3] }, { num: [4, 5, 6] });
//   ^? { num: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] }
```

How to do it?

- Flat

  Let's try by simply using TypeScript spread syntax for variadic tuples:

  ```
  type t1a = [1, 2, 3]
  type t2a = [4, 5, 6]

  type ra = [...t1a, ...t2a]
  //   ^? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  // awesome, works
  ```

  Let's try it using generic TypeScript function (with the help of [this blog](https://learntypescript.dev/06/l9-generic-spread)):

  ```
  function fa<T1 extends number[], T2 extends number[]>(t1: [...T1], t2: [...T2]): [...T1, ...T2] {
    return [...t1, ...t2];
  }
  const rfa = fa([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]);
  //   ^? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  // awesome, works
  ```
- Nested

  Let's try spreading types on nested prop:

  ```
  type t1b = { num: [1, 2, 3] }
  type t2b = { num: [4, 5, 6] }

  type rtb = [...t1b['num'], ...t2b['num']]
  //   ^? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  // awesome, works
  ```

  Now with generics:

  ```
  function fc<T1 extends { num: number[] }, T2 extends { num: number[] }>(
    t1: T1,
    t2: T2,
  ): { num: [...T1['num'], ...T2['num']] } {
    return { num: [...t1.num, ...t2.num] as any };
  }
  const rfc = fc({ num: [1, 2, 3] }, { num: [4, 5, 6] });
  //   ^?  {num: number[]}
  // why?? why not [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ??
  ```

  Why is `rfc` not `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` as I would expect?

Comment: Because `T1 extends {num: number[]}` gives no hint that you care about anything more specific than `number[]` for `num` (the most common use for this would be that `T1` would have properties aside from `num`, not to narrow `num` to some tuple of literals).  You can use a `const` type parameter to ask for more specific inference, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mq0g2N). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: hey, actually your answer is better than mine, never knew about `const T1 extends` syntax. you can write it as an answer and I would accept it

Comment: I'll do so when I get a chance.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76103239/2100372 which was also answered by @jcalz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript only infers [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) and [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) in certain circumstances, and a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T1` or `T2` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `{ num: number[] }` is not one of them.  (You can look at [microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) to see a description of some of the situations in which literal types are inferred.) The compiler interprets `T1 extends { num: number[] }` to mean something like "`T1` will at least have a `num` property of type `number[]` and it might have more properties too", and it's not looking to infer anything more specific than `number[]` for `num`.

If you want the compiler to infer more specific types for literal values, you need to give it a hint to do so.  A *caller* of your `fc()` function could use [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to do so, such as

```
const rfc = fc({ num: [1, 2, 3] } as const, { num: [4, 5, 6] } as const);
// T1 = readonly { num: [1, 2, 3] }
// T2 = readonly { num: [4, 5, 6] }
// const rfc: { num: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; }
```

But if a caller forgets to do this it won't happen.

---

Luckily, TypeScript 5.0 introduced [the `const` modifer for generic type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters), so that you can mark `T1` and `T2` as types parameter whose type arguments should mostly be treated *as if* the caller had used `as const`.  Like this:

```
function fc<
  const T1 extends { num: number[] },
  const T2 extends { num: number[] }
>(t1: T1, t2: T2): { num: [...T1['num'], ...T2['num']] } {
  return { num: [...t1.num, ...t2.num] as any };
}
```

Now when you call `fc()`, you get the following behavior:

```
const rfc = fc({ num: [1, 2, 3] }, { num: [4, 5, 6] });
// T1 = readonly { num: [1, 2, 3] }
// T2 = readonly { num: [4, 5, 6] }
// const rfc: { num: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; }
```

So `T1` and `T2` are inferred to be the same types as before, even though the caller did not use `as const` anywhere.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBKBhA9sKAXJA3gFBJIBmArsPLgJbbnwA8JpSAKgIxIQAeuEYABMohJMApgAXOMkAjCACcA2gF0kAXwA0rUuwBMPfoJFiJ02WAUr1G1gD4AFLk4yuWpLn1v9AShkEljLKAHRhXMoA5OaRqh5hIQZRMaq2hLpIihC4FIrAZpLBCS4h5vFhXqWS6iCiIMAAnpoA3Kx2pPDYeJlk8EgAvIyOgebBnB76HgDMabVInTi4HiOFSMoALB4ArB4AbLOiC3i+raQA9Gcc3INZIELYADZNKxbK40iTSDOarBcchjcIHdHs8gmtNkgdkh9j9zpcjvhFL0AmC3hNph4IVD9s0fnYiKBILAEMgsIsAAogRTgdKkSjUOgMXosNjzLr4LhGATCUQvGTmaxqTQ6VkI-5cky8sECpRC9pIJwuNzvLw+fwFV4JCLRSSxcqJfTJXWpTS0thZHJ5DVFCqcKpgfWVcw1OqNFptVhipF9Qa9Yao96fb7aa3g7Z7WwnX6XTmA4HAJ6htEfaa2aPiuP3BOg0ZhyER2FIP5e5FJwMYpBYiO4uwaIA)

Answer (score 0):

I was just missing a 'const' statement on array:

```
const rfc = fc({ num: [1, 2, 3] as const }, { num: [4, 5, 6] as const });
```